Is double possessive applicable in “the names of the parents’ in the film”?
I have a question about double possessives. Here are 2 sentences:

The names of the parents’ in the film are Kate and Peter.
The names of the parents in the film are Kate and Peter.

I understand that the second sentence is correct, but is the first also possible?
If the first sentence is not grammatically correct, can you explain why the double possessive cannot be used in this case?

@livresque To my mind that proposed duplicate is too muddied by its confusion over "friend of Peter" vs "friend of Peter's." Tom: I don't see a reason that #1 should be wrong (though I also don't see a need to use it). To get better answers, please explain why you're concerned about it.

The first is wrong, because it duplicates 'of' with the apostrophe. "The parents' names were..."

@WeatherVane That's the whole idea of the double possessive.

@livresque Not nearly the same. Different in so many different ways it's difficult to know where to start! Let's start here: no pronoun, and no singular noun phrase. Please withdraw your downvote.

I've found no supporting material for this, but I think it's correct.
With

some friends of my parents',

a 'non-intrinsic' property/association is involved: my parents' friends are not an attribute of my parents. There is a looser association.
Similarly with

some dirty shirts of Jim's
those old ties of mine.

This type, showing true ownership/proprietorship, is often found as a double possessive/genitive.
But with

the names of the parents in the film
the attitudes of the team

there is an intrinsic, identifying association, which I'd say bars or strongly discourages the double genitive construction.
But sometimes with non-intrinsic associations, there is a choice, with perhaps subtle differences in meaning. Both the following can be found on the internet:

He is no friend of England.
He is no friend of England's.


Thank you. This was helpful.

Interestingly, the intrinsic type can (just about) work if we swap the simple article for a deictic determiner: I can think of contexts where “these/those names of the parents’ in the film” would be possible – or if not precisely that, perhaps, then at least equivalent constructions, like ‘that name of yours’.

You can’t do the friends of my parents’ are going to the party but you can do some friends of my parents’ are going to the party. You can’t do the attitude of the team’s will cost us the championship but you can do that attitude of the team’s will cost us the championship. @JanusBahsJacquet

@TinfoilHat Double possessives always require a ‘strong’ modifier (demonstrative, relative clause, etc.). The main difference here is intrinsicality: with non-intrinsic possessives, the double possessive is very natural and common; with intrinsic possessives, the double possession is clunkier and much less frequent, especially with non-pronominal possessors. “That attitude of the team’s will cost us the championship”, for example, is possible, but much less likely than “The team’s attitude will cost us the championship”.

In Old English, off and of were the same word, distinguished only by emphasis. If “of” were emphasised, it gave us “off” and "off" was partitive.
Compare
“I took it off the shelf” and “I took it from the shelf” and
“It is made of steel” and “It is made from steel” and
“The apples off this tree are sour” and “The apples of this tree are sour” and “The apples from this tree are sour.”
In the double genitive, the of in
Friends/a friend of my parents', is the of  that equates to the Modern German “von” which designates an origin or source for its noun (it is partitive). Off/of thus also has a parallel in “from”.
And parents’ is a genitive pronoun -> from [among] my parents’ friends
Likewise:
Friends/a friend of mine',
And of mine  = from [among] my friends.
This “of” thus equates to “from [among]” (“Take one of those apples” -> “Take one from [among] those apples.”)
Thus
Friends/a friend of my parents', -> Friends/a friend from among my parents' friends,
Friends/a friend of my mine -> Friends/a friend from among my friends
Thus in your example:
*The names of the parents’ in the film are Kate and Peter. = The names from among the parents’ names in the film are Kate and Peter.
The names of the parents in the film are Kate and Peter. = The parents’ names in the film are Kate and Peter.
If you do not have a second genitive, the “of” carries the far broader meaning, i.e. “contextually associated with.”
Thus we can understand ambiguous phrases like Bob's photograph, which could refer either to a photograph of Bob (that is, revealing Bob's image) or to one in Bob's possession. A photograph of Bob's can only be a photo that Bob has in his possession, which may or may not show Bob's image, as it means one photograph from among Bob’s photographs.
